# Serializable trait not sticking in Scala with SBT/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, serialization, sbt

I have a hierarchy in Scala with some marker traits. At the top of the hierarchy I declare the root trait to be Serializable. Several layers down, when I get to concrete objects, inheritors of the trait seem to forget that they are Serializable. The hierarchy looks like this:

```
trait DataModel extends Serializable              // Marker trait
trait StaticModel extends DataModel               // Marker trait
trait RectangleModel[T] extends StaticModel {     // Trait with type param
  def rows: Int
  def columns: Int
  def apply(row: Int, column: Int): Option[T]
}

object MakeRectangleModelFromFile {               // Factory object
  def apply(file: File): RectangleModel[String] = 
    new RectangleModel[String] {                  // Anonymous class that
      def rows = 2                                // implements the trait.
      def columns = 3
      def apply(row:Int, column:Int): Option[String] = Some("One")
    }
}

val x = MakeRectangleModelFromFile(null)          // Make object using factory.
println(x.isInstanceOf[Serializable])             // Object should be Serializable!
```

When I compile and run from the command line (Scala 2.10.3) the last statement prints out "true", as expected. When I do the same from Eclipse using Scala IDE for Eclipse, and a project created by SBT 0.13, I get "false". The concrete data model seems to have forgotten that it is Serializable. If I remind it that it is Serializable, by constructing it as follows:

```
new RectangleModel[String] with Serializable {
  ...
}
```

All is well again! I am wondering if there is something fishy in the SBT cache, maybe having to do with the trait being generic. I've produced a similar example with a named subclass of RectangleModel, so I don't think it's a problem with the class being anonymous.

Back when I first wrote the RectangleModel[T] trait, I forgot to make it extend StaticModel, and so there was a time when the compiler had it right. But now it seems like the compiler is remembering that prior time. Even when I Scaladoc this stuff, Scaladoc shows that the RectangleModel is Serializable.

Any clues as to how to flush out this old, bad memory?

Comment: Have you tried "sbt clean"?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code on GitHub so all it takes to get started with the project and fix it is to `clone` it?

Comment: Have tried sbt clean. Also tried fiddling with the code so that it forced a recompile. Will try to get code to GitHub.